# Garrysmod SQL wrapper

Tags: mysql, lua

```lua
require( "mysqloo" )
require( "tmysql4" )


isqldb = mysqloo.connect(DETAILS) || { }
isql = isqldb || { }

--[[---------------------------------------------------------
    Initialises iSQL
-----------------------------------------------------------]]
function isql.Connect(addr, u, p, database)

        print( "MySQL Connecting:", addr )
        isqldb = mysqloo.connect(addr, u, p, database, 3306)

        -- tsql hack
        tmysql.initialize(addr, u, p, database, 3306)

        function isqldb.onConnected()
            print( "MySQL Server Version:", self:serverVersion() )
            print( "MySQL Server Info:", self:serverInfo() )
            print( "MySQL Host Info:", self:hostInfo() )


            Msg("iSQL: Sucessfully connected to " .. addr .."\n")

        end

        function isqldb.onConnectionFailed(self, error)

            print( "MySQL Connection Failed! Error:", error )

        end

        isqldb:connect()

        return true
    end



--[[---------------------------------------------------------
    Query 
-----------------------------------------------------------]]
function isql.Query( query, qtype )
        if not isqldb then
            MsgN("premature db call:")
            debug.Trace()
        end

        local q = isqldb:query( query )
        q:start()
        q:wait()
        if (q:error() == "") then
            return q:getData(), true
        else
            q:error()
            return nil, false
        end

    end
```

I'm trying to run this to connect and execute ony my mysql server but it won't connect or debug. Can anyone notice where im going wrong?

This is using mysqloo and tmysql4 or should i just use mysqloo
It doesn't even say successfully connected im not sure why

Comment: Can you connect to your MySQL instance via the command line or Workbench?  Let's try to rule that out first.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how either Mysqloo nor tmysql4, and you really shouldn't use both of them together.

Lets go ahead now:
It's DATABASE_METATABLE:onConnected() with a ":" not a "."

Same for all methods which are functions in Mysqloo.

Why write queries like that?
You have QUERY_METATABLE:onSuccess(data) and QUERY_METATABLE:onError(err, sql)

Good luck